# arecord throw Input/Output error

Tags: audio, alsa, hat

When trying to run the following command, I am getting Input/Output error

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo arecord -Dhw:1,0 -d 10 -f cd -t wav test.wav
Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
arecord: pcm_read:2031: read error: Input/output error

I am using the HAT audio hardware ported from 4.4.12 to 4.9.38-v7. The utility "arecord -l" shows the HAT driver installed.

Is there anything need to modify.

### Output of "arecord"

- pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -Dhw:0,0 -d 10 -f cd -t wav test.wav
- Output >>> 
  arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
- pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -l
- Output >>> 
  **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices **** card 1: sndrpis5adcdac 
  [snd_rpi_s5_adcdac], device 0: S5 ADCDAC HiFi tlv320aic31xx-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Can you add the output of : arecord -l , I suggest to try -Dhw:0,0 , if you have only one recording input I don't see why it would be 1,0.

Comment: @YCN: added output of "arecord -l"

Comment: Try to touch the test.wav first and then try this simple command : arecord -f dat -d 20 -D hw:0,0 test.wav it should record 20s of dat quality sound into test.wav

Comment: @YCN: still same error

Comment: Then something wrong, you should uninstall the driver and make it all over again. I feel like you might have missed something. How's the hat plugged  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue by adding "dtparam=audio=off" in /boot/config.txt.

@YCN: Thank you for your time.